# How to apply style using GtkSourceView library

Tags: gtk3, gtksourceview

I'm trying to style a GtkSourceView object in particular I'd like to change the color of line numbers. I'm reading [Style Scheme Definition Reference: GtkSourceView 4 Reference Manual](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/style-reference.html). I'm able to change `text` but not `line-numbers`. The document says:

line-numbers : Text and background colors for the left margin, on which line numbers are drawn.

This is the source:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtksourceview/gtksource.h>

int main (int argc,
char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *scrolled_win, *textview;
    GtkWidget *vbox, *menubar, *fileMenu, *fileMi, *quit_item;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_maximize(GTK_WINDOW (window));
    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 12);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Text Views");
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    textview = gtk_source_view_new();
    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
    fileMenu = gtk_menu_new();

    fileMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("File");

    quit_item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");

    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(textview, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(textview, TRUE);

    GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (provider,
    "gtk-widgets.css", NULL);

    GtkStyleContext *context;
    context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(textview);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider (context,
                                    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
                                    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(fileMi), fileMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), quit_item);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), fileMi);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    scrolled_win = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), scrolled_win);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_win), textview);

    gtk_source_view_set_show_line_numbers (GTK_SOURCE_VIEW(textview), TRUE);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quit_item), "activate",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the CSS file:

```css
text {
    background-color: #002b36;
    color: #c7a21d;
}

line-numbers {
    background-color: red;
    color:red;
}

current-line-number {
    background-color: red;
    color:red;
}

selection{
    color:yellow;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `GtkSourceView` say anywhere that CSS is to be used to style it? That page is about its own "Style Scheme Definition XML format" and has no occurrence of the term _CSS_. Did you get the instruction to use CSS from elsewhere? How are you compiling and loading the CSS? Does perhaps `.line-numbers` work, assuming the drawing uses a style class and not a node name?

Comment: No it doesn't the only selectors that work are `text` and `selection`. Can you show me how could I style with XML?

Comment: Sorry, no; I would just have to go and read the documentation, which it seems you already started ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The [API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GtkSource-3.0/classes/StyleSchemeManager.html#GtkSource.StyleSchemeManager) has a way to access the default styles like this:

```
manager = GtkSource.StyleSchemeManager().get_default()

print (manager.get_scheme_ids())
>['classic', 'cobalt', 'kate', 'oblivion', 'solarized-dark', 'solarized-light', 'tango']

scheme = manager.get_scheme("oblivion")
buffer.set_style_scheme(scheme)
```

An example for good measure:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk
from gi.repository import GtkSource as gtksource
from gi.repository import Pango

view = gtksource.View()
view.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('monospace 11'))
view.set_show_line_numbers(True)
view.set_show_line_marks(True)
buffer = view.get_buffer()
filename = "treeview.py"
txt = open(filename).read()
buffer.set_text(txt)
# set language, syntax highlighting
lm = gtksource.LanguageManager.new()
lang = lm.guess_language(filename)
buffer.set_highlight_syntax(True)
buffer.set_language(lang)
buffer.create_tag("invisible",invisible=True)
manager = gtksource.StyleSchemeManager().get_default()
scheme = manager.get_scheme("monokai")
buffer.set_style_scheme(scheme)
window = gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
window.add(view)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

[image: output]

From there you should be able use the [guide](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/style-reference.html) to apply custom themes, change colours of certain elements, etc...

Comment: The question asks for C code and this answers with offtopic Python code...